# 2 Parent BLOGs in DNN 5.x?

Tags: blogs, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I have created 2 parent BLOGs in DNN. BLOG x has 3 children BLOGs and BLOG y has 5 children.

When I click Add BLOG entry, only BLOG x & is children come up in the dropdown list, BLOG y is missing. Anyone know why?  Even if I go to the BLOG y and click Add BLOG entry, its missing.

Many thanks,
Tony.

Answer (score 0):

I got it!

The 2 blogs were created by 2 different users...!!!! Therefore, only the user that created the blog can add entries.

But how can you change the owner of the blog to another user?

Comment: You would have to change the owner of the blog in the DB if i remember right.